# How get decimal keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to display decimal keyboard programatically for UITextField.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `myTextField` is an `IBOutlet` in your controller, you could do this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```